# Retain a Function Block with FB_Init method

Tags: codesys

If I have a Function Block with an explicitly defined `FB_Init` method, I can't seem to use the `Retain` keyword, as I get a `C0138:  No matching FB_init method found for instantiation of POU` error, for example:

```c
FUNCTION_BLOCK POU1
VAR
    _val: INT;
END_VAR
```

```c
METHOD FB_Init : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains : BOOL;
    bInCopyCode : BOOL;
    val: INT;
END_VAR
THIS^._val := val;
```

```c
PROGRAM SR_Main
VAR RETAIN
    p1: POU1(val := 10); // C0138:  No matching FB_init method found for instantiation of POU1
END_VAR
```

The project seems to build without error, until I try to run a simulation that fails with the above error. I am using Machine Expert 1.2.3 (CODESYS 3.5.12 I believe)

How do I retain Function Blocks with FB_Init methods?

PS. The only way I found so far, is to manually write the `RETAIN` keyword on every `VAR` type inside the Function Block (`VAR`, `VAR_OUTPUT`), but then I'll have to have 2 separate version of this object (unretained, and retained, like `POU1` and `POU1_RETAINED` for example), not to mention that, that will not work with `PERSISTENT`.

Comment: I tried your code on Twincat 3 and Codesys 3.5 and I'm not experiencing any issues. On both platforms the code runs without any problems.

Comment: @FilippoBoido, I'll remind you, just building the project didn't result in any errors, but running a simulation resulted in the error above, and a log: "No bootproject file $PlcLogic$/Sim.LMC_PacDrive.Application/Sim.LMC_PacDrive.Application.app available!". If your simulation is running without problems, then I'll try contacting Schneider directly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @FilippoBoido, I just downloaded CODESYS 3.5.16 and can confirm that everything seems to work as intended. If you make an Answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from Guiorgy runs as intended on both Twincat 3 and Codesys 3.5.

The error, which occurs when running the example using Machine Expert, must be a specific Schneider issue.

Comment: This is a little off topic, but do you know of a way to prevent the retention of a local variable inside a function block? e.i. suppose POU1 has the keyword RETAIN, and POU1 has val1: INT and val2: INT. In such case, I only want to retain val1, and I want to reset val2.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean.Formulate a new question with more details please.

Comment: I did so, would you please have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059799/prevent-local-variable-retention